# Why do ID attributes need stricter validation?

Tags: web-application, xss, validation

According to [OWASP XSS Prevention Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#XSS_Prevention_Rules_Summary), one should

> Strictly validate unsafe attributes such as background, id and name

I understand that `background` could contain `data:` urls, and can therefore be exploited even if the content is HTML encoded according to [Rule 2](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#RULE_.232_-_Attribute_Escape_Before_Inserting_Untrusted_Data_into_HTML_Common_Attributes).

But why do I have to strictly validate `id` and `name`? Is it just because it can be used to inject anchors which could trigger event handlers that were injected by other means? Or is it to prevent DOM-based XSS because of vulnerable scripts that load code from elements using the ID (i.e. shadowing some other element that is present in the page)?

Answer (score 3):

This is not to prevent double quotes, single quotes or spaces from breaking out of the attribute context, as this is covered by "Aggressive HTML Entity Encoding".

For `background`, an attack [like this](http://www.acunetix.com/websitesecurity/cross-site-scripting/) is possible:

```
<body background="javascript:alert('XSS')">
```

For `id` and `name`, these attributes are frequently used as reference points in the DOM.

If an attacker can spoof these reference points, she may be able trick existing scripts into getting and setting values from places other than designed, which may be dangerous depending on the context that is is used.

This also applies to HTML forms where `name` is used to identify the name/value pair. For example, if a website does not encode a particular form field when it is output, but since the form field is server generated and the form is protected against CSRF by the use of tokens it cannot be exploited by normal means. However, an attacker may be able to entice a user to visit a URL with a parameter that is used in `name`, containing an XSS payload to execute on submission of the form.

e.g. Normal use:

```
https://example.com/product?item_name=watch&qty=1
```

which renders a form

```
<form>

<input type="hidden" name="watch" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="shop_name" value="Bob's Supplies" />
<input type="hidden" name="anti-csrf" value="asdjasodhoai" />

<input type="submit" value="Click here to buy" />

</form>
```

And then gets output as

```
Thank you for buying from Bob's Supplies.
```

However, an attacker could send a link to the user like so:

```
https://example.com/product?item_name=shop_name&qty=<script>alert('xss')</script>
```

As the application is correctly HTML encoding at this point it renders the form as

```
<form>

<input type="hidden" name="shop_name" value="&lt;script&gt;alert(&#039;xss&#039;)&lt;/script&gt;" />
<input type="hidden" name="shop_name" value="Bob's Supplies" />
<input type="hidden" name="anti-csrf" value="asdjasodhoai" />

<input type="submit" value="Click here to buy" />

</form>
```

This then gets output as

```
Thank you for buying from <script>alert('xss')</script>.
```

since this page doesn't HTML encode the `shop_name` parameter because it is trusted and the application framework always takes the first value in case of duplicates. Very contrived, but it was the first thing that fell into my head to demonstrate the point.

Comment: Hmm, background and JS? I don't get why you referenced `<body background="javascript:alert('XSS')">` here, it doesn't even work in any of the 9 major browsers (I tested with IE, Chrome, FF, Opera, Safari, Seamonkey, Avant, Baidu, Torch).

Comment: It did used to be an attack when used in the browsers of old, that's why OWASP recommend that it is validated.

Answer (score 0):

The text is saying that you need to validate untrusted input when used as any attribute. It is just a restatement of [rule 2](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#RULE_.232_-_Attribute_Escape_Before_Inserting_Untrusted_Data_into_HTML_Common_Attributes). Characters such as `"` could cause big problems.

Comment: I disagree. Rule 2 is explicitly about "safe attributes" such as "width, name, value, etc", and only requires HTML encoding.

Comment: @0x89 - Yes, it is reminding you that you still must check "safe" attributes because, for example, `"><script>...</script>` even in a safe attribute will allow code injection.